# I have problems with DOM in javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

*Text editor*: Visual studio code

*Browser*: Firefox

*OS*: Fedora 31

and with node, I get "document is not defined" 
I'm new so I don't know what to do?

My error:

> TypeError: lovers.style is undefined

```js
let lovers = document.getElementsByClassName("lover");
lovers.style.color = "red";
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>traning</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" S>

</head>

<body>
    <li class="title">2435</li>
    <li class="lover">4534</li>
    <li class="hater">s43343</li>
</body>
<script src="./app.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: node dosn't need a browser to execute its JS code, so it won't have access to the `document`

Comment: Also `getElementsBy*` returns a HTMLCollection (not a singleelement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getElementsByClassName` method of `Document` interface returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class names. This object does not contain the `style` property. To make this work, you need to extract the first element from the array using `[0]`.

```
let lovers = document.getElementsByClassName("lover")[0];
lovers.style.color = "red";
```